# Elegant way to split hex string at byte 00?

Tags: javascript, regex, string, split, hex

I need to split a hex string at every `00` byte.  I tried this:

```
string.split('00');
```

But that causes splits at `5009`, for instance, which is incorrect because it is splitting a byte in half.

In other words, it turns `5009` to `[5, 9]`, which I don't want.  But I do want it to turn `af0059` to `[af, 59]`.

Is it even possible to split bytes using regex, without cutting any bytes in half?

I could use a loop to seek through the string and only divide the string at even-number indices, but I would much prefer a regex expression.

Comment: Why is my question being downvoted literally immediately?

Comment: You aren't `.split()`ing a Hex number, you are operating on a string. There is definition of a "two character" byte in a string. (I did not downvote you).

Comment: I thought I used the term `hex string` correctly.  I didn't call it a `hex number`, after all.

Comment: My point is a string is a string is a string. In UTF-16 there are two bytes per char, yet you are referring to two character's per byte (as if it were a hexidecimal number).

Comment: So I should use the term nibble?

Comment: Could you please provide a sample string and its expected output?

Comment: I apologize I wasn't clear at first in the OP, I did edit to hopefully clarify.  But here is another example: I want to go from `af00b9e00f70` to `[af, b9e00f70]`

Comment: I can give a somewhat old school solution, but before I do let me understand... the string *IS* filled with hex digits, where each pair is one digit, correct?

Comment: That is correct.  I am in the process of trying out the solution provided in the answer below though.

Comment: Update: The answer below does not work, I explained why in a comment to it.

Comment: @CocoDaWhiteBerry I haven't looked at it specifically, as I was digging up my own example/solution when it was posted. But if the solution turned out NOT to work, shouldn't you uncheck it as the "final answer" and check one that does?  (and I don't know if Stackoverflow even lets you do this)

Comment: I actually was referring to the first answer.  Since I made the comment you replied to I actually got the correct answer and chose it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe not the most elegant, but it works

```js
const inp = "af00b9e00f70"
const out = inp.match(/.{1,2}/g).map(a=>a=="00"?"_":a).join("").split("_");
console.log(out);
```

Comment: Hey this is exactly the sort of elegance I was looking for, this might be the shortest code possible to accomplish my objective.  It works perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

Because of the byte sizes, you need to first `split` the string into byte-sizes, then `map` and finally `join`.

```js
const string = "af00b9e00f70";
const res = string.split(/([\d\w]{4})/).filter(e => e).map(e => e.replace(/00([\d\w]{2})/, "$1").replace(/([\d\w]{2})00/, "$1")).join("");
console.log(res);
```

Comment: Nevermind.  This isn't working. `af00b9e00f70` turns to `[ 'af', 'b9e0', '0f70' ]` when I remove the `join("")`.  I don't want it to split `b9e00f70` into 2 separate strings.  Because that involves splitting a pair of characters in half.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a somewhat "old school' approach, but it demonstrates the principal. I say "old school' because we had to do this all the time back in the days of assembler coding. 'string' contains your long string of hex pairs (bytes). Here I convert it to byte values. Change the 'string' to whatever you want, but be sure it has an even number of hex digits. Call 'translate' to demonstrate it, and format the output into an alert() (or just output to the console)

```
var values = []; // output array
var string = "000102030405060708090a0b0c0d0e0f1FFFFEFDFCFBFAF9F8F7F6F5F4F3F2F0";

function getHexByteValues( string) {
    var hex= "0123456789ABCDEF";
    var outIx=0;

    for (var i =0; i <= (string.length-2); i +=2) { // skip every other
        //get higher and lower nibble
         var hexdig1 = string.substring(i, i+1);
         var hexdig0 = string.substring(i+1, i+2);
         // for simplicity, convert alpha to upper case
         hexdig1 = hexdig1.toUpperCase();
         hexdig0 = hexdig0.toUpperCase();

         // convert hex to decimal value.
         // position in lookup string == value
         var dec1 = hex.indexOf(hexdig1);
         var dec0 = hex.indexOf(hexdig0);

         // calc "byte" value, and add to values.
         values[outIx++] = dec1 * 16 + dec0;
        }
    }


function translate(string) {
    getHexByteValues(string);
    var output="";

    for (var i =0; i < values.length; i++)  {
        output += i + " = " + values[i] + "\r\n";
        }
    alert (output);
    }
```

Comment: note that to to improve the call to work with word or 32 bit values, you might add an 'inner' loop, whose limit is the number of nibbles/value. Or to convert complex structures, where a string of hex represents different object sizes at different offsets, you might need to include a "map" array, where each element dictates the number of nibble to parse. Then, of course, you have the old issues of knowing the "byte order" of any objects with 2 or more bytes. The above code can be streamlined or expanded, but its a start